# Find objects with the most correspondences to a reference object

Tags: algorithm, pattern-recognition

Reference object: { 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11 }

Other objects:

```
A   { 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11 }
B   { 5, 7, 9, 10 }
C   { 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12 }
D   { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 }
E   { 6, 8 }
F   { 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15 }
... { ... }
```

Difficulty: It should be faster than O(n*m)

Result should be:

```
Array
(
    [D] => 5
    [A] => 4
    [C] => 3
    [B] => 3
    [F] => 2
    [E] => 1
)
```

Slow solution:

```
ref = array(1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11);

foreach (A, B, C, D,.. AS row)
{
    foreach (row AS col)
    {   
        if ( exist(col, ref) )
        {
            result[row] += 1;
        }
    }
}

sort (result)
```

.. this is a solution, but its far to slow.

Is there another way like patter recognition, hopefully in O(log n)?

It is possible to save each object in an other notation, like for example:

```
ref = "15691011"
A = "2456811"
```

But I don't know if this helps.

Comment: Can there be repitions in any input array? Are all the arrays always sorted initially?

Comment: If you have `m` sequences and each has length `n` you will not get faster than `O(n*m)` because you must at least read all your input.

Comment: Sounds like the good old nearest neighbors problem. Try a kd-tree or ball tree, after preprocessing your input to get it in a proper vector space.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all data in your objects sorted, you can do this routine faster, by comparing not single values in the row, but whole row step by step.

```
foreach (A, B, C, D,.. AS row)
{
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < row.length && j < ref.length)
    {
        if (row[i] < ref[j]) i++;
        elseif (row[i] > ref[j]) j++;
        else {
            result[row] += 1;
            i++; j++;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case you pass you reference only once for each row, but this algorithm need all your data to be already sorted.

Comment: Good Idea. You also need to increment both counters if their indices' values match.

Comment: Abhishek, thanks a lot for useful addition, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could start with the largest sequence (it has the largest change to have many references).
When you find - for example - 4 refs, you can safely skip all sequences with less then 4 elements.

Another early exit is to abort checking a sequence, when the current sequence cannot surpass the current max. for example: Your current max is 6 elements. You are processing a list of size 7, but the first two elements are no reference. The highest reachable for this list is 5, which is lower than 6, abort the sequence.

Problem in both cases is that you can not construct a complete array of results.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

```
There are m lists apart from the reference object.
The lists are sorted initially.
There are no repetition of elements in any array.
```

1. Scan all the arrays and find out the maximum element in all the lists. You only need to check the last element in each list. Call it MAX.
2. For each of the m + 1 lists, make a corresponding Boolean array with MAX elements and initialize their values to zero.
3. Scan all the arrays and make the corresponding indices of arrays 1.

   For example, the corresponding array for the example reference object { 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11 } shall look like:
   {1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,...}
4. Now for every pair-wise combination, you can just check the corresponding indices and increment the count if both are 1.

The above algorithm can be done in linear time complexity with regards to the total number of elements in the data.

Comment: Actually, we can compress this structures to bitsets (or something like BigIntegers), then, by using bitwise operators (`and` for this case) get vector of similar elements and get amount of set bits in `O(number of set bits)`. But this approach will work only and only if MAX is small enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should use other techniques used in search engines. For each number,  you have a list of object contained this number in sorted order. In your case

```
1  -> {D, F}    
5  -> {A, B, C, D}
6  -> {A, C, D, E}
9  -> {B, C, D, F}
10 -> {A, B, D}
11 -> {A}
```

Merging this list you can count how your object is similar to objects in list

```
A -> 4
B -> 3
C -> 2
D -> 5
E -> 1
F -> 2
```

After sorting, you get needed result. If you need only top k elements, you should use a priority queue.